# Sub all the specified regex interval except some characters

Tags: python, regex, arabic, python-re

For example, I want to replace all the data going from the specified intervals with `*` (except the chars `u0650, u0660, u064F`), for example.

Note: I don't want to break the interval because I have a lot of characters to preserve.

```
data = re.sub(r'[\u0600-\u061E\u0620-\u065F\u0670-\u06ef]', "*", data)
```

Comment: Side note: `\u660` is not included in your character class so it doesn't really need to be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the characters to be excluded in a negative Lookahead *before* the main character class.

For example:

```regex
(?![\u0650\u0660\u064F])[\u0600-\u061E\u0620-\u065F\u0670-\u06ef]
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xpa9l/1)**.